# Drizzle - accessing array items from a getter

Tags: truffle, arrays, drizzle

In my contract I have a getter function that returns a full array of addresses:

```
function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(address[] memory) {
    return deployedCampaigns;
}
```

Using drizzle I have the following code for my component that returns the content of that array:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ReadCampaigns extends Component {

  state = { dataKey: null};

  componentDidMount() {
    const { drizzle, drizzleState } = this.props;

    const contract = drizzle.contracts.CampaignFactory;

      const dataKey = contract.methods["getDeployedCampaigns"].cacheCall({from: drizzleState.accounts[1], gas: 3000000});

    this.setState({ dataKey });
  }

  render() {
    const { CampaignFactory } = this.props.drizzleState.contracts;

    const campaigns = CampaignFactory.getDeployedCampaigns[this.state.dataKey];
    console.log(campaigns); 
    return <p> Campaigns: {campaigns && campaigns.value}</p>;
  }
}

export default ReadCampaigns;
```

And the following:

```
console.log(campaigns);
```

returns this to the console:

```
{args: Arguments(0), fnIndex: 3, value: Array(2)}
args: Arguments [callee: (...), Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
fnIndex: 3
value: Array(2)
0: "0x6aA54653EEE943cb0a9DF41ee890A9c25f8b9210"
1: "0x2Fc343d40c0a643B30401A0A1788ec6F55e0EdD0"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Now, my expectation was that I would be able to map through campaigns.value, however:

```
console.log(campaigns.value)
```

returns undefined.

Seems like I am missing something, because the following statement:

```
{campaigns && campaigns.value}
```

produces a list of all addresses as expected, however they are concatenated.

Could somebody kindly explain what I am missing in my thinking process? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following works because `render` is called once before `componentDidMount` which will initialize the data needed by `render`. [See React docs for more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting)

```
    {campaigns && campaigns.value}
```

You will have to keep track of when your data has been initialized so when it is not initialized you can render an appropriate `...loading...` message. The test app for Drizzle React Components does it like [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react-components/blob/develop/test-app/app/src/MyComponent.js#L18)